# Exponent Laws and Square Roots of Squares

Tags: exponentiation, radicals

There are several questions on the square root of a squared number. But mine is a little different, because under the pre-condition, that the square root function maps onto positive reals, using laws for radicals and exponents I *do* can verify for myself, that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ and that $\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2 = x$. However when I apply exponent laws I get a contradiction, therefore apparently exponent laws do not work for fractions as they do for whole numbers. However I have not heard of that distinction so far. Is this the case, or where is the fault in my reasoning?

An example:

\begin{align*}
  \left( \sqrt{-5} \right)^2 & = \left( \sqrt{5}i \right)^2\\
                             & =  \left(\sqrt{5}  \right)^2 (-1)\\
                             & =  5 (-1)\\
                             & =  -5\\
                             \text{on the other hand:}\\
  \sqrt{(-5)^2}              & = \sqrt{25}\\
                             & = 5\\
  \text{however:}\\
  \left( \sqrt{-5} \right)^2 &= \left( (-5)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right)^2 = (-5)^1 = \left( (-5)^{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{(-5)^2}
\end{align*}

Which would be a contradiction.

Comment: `under the pre-condition, that the square root function maps onto positive reals` That's only true for $x \in \mathbb{R^+}\,$ and $-5$ is *not* a positive real number.

Comment: @dxiv ok, but that does not resolve the problem as I see it, does it.

Comment: $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ safely when $a$ is positive (real or integer) and $b$ and $c$ are real, and also when $a$ is non-zero (real or complex) and $b$ and $c$ are integers.  Your example does not fit either case

Comment: @user3578468 See for example [What are the Laws of Rational Exponents?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628759/what-are-the-laws-of-rational-exponents?rq=1).