# When do rational exponents produce two answers?

Tags: exponentiation

I am wondering when rational exponents produce two answers.

I am aware that X^2=25 produces two answers and why this is the case.  I have not found a good resource for every case.

1. What is (-2)^(2/2)?  If we take the square root first, do we need to use i?  Is there a rule about whether a power or root comes first in this case?  What if we re write this as the root of (-2), squared?
2. How do we solve things like the following correctly?

A.  X^(4/2) = 10

B.  X^(3/2) = 10

3. What is the general system for determining when absolute value (i.e. two answers) come into play?

Comment: Related: [What are the Laws of Rational Exponents?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1628759/409).