# Is it true that $\left(-\frac{1}{64}\right)^{-\frac 43}=256$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, definition

[image]

I have included this picture in its original form from my textbook here.

I think this is wrong because it contradicts the definition of $a^x$.

Because we define

$$a^x=e^{x\ln a}$$

where $a>0,x\in\mathbb R$.

Am I making a mistake or is the textbook wrong?

Comment: $a < 0$ in your example

Comment: The expression is not even defined with *your* definition. Maybe the book uses a different definition? The question is borderline duplicate of [What are the Laws of Rational Exponents?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628759/what-are-the-laws-of-rational-exponents).

Comment: @dxiv I think that the definition must be global and solid, right?

Comment: @I'mastudent Solid, yes. Global/universal, not necessarily. Each book can tell the story in its own words, as long as the definitions are clearly stated and the language is consistent throughout.

Comment: @dxiv but $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$ is not my definition..

Comment: @I'mastudent But you still aren't saying whether that definition comes from the same textbook that you are asking about. If yes, then the quoted line does not even make sense because the leftmost expression is not defined according to that definition.

Comment: @dxiv I took the definition $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$ from wikipedia, not from the book..

Comment: @I'mastudent Find the definition in *that* book and [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4336683/edit) *that* one into the question.

Comment: @dxiv there is no definition for negative base in the textbook. Only example.

Comment: @I'mastudent Then find a better textbook. You won't learn good math from a book that throws some random manipulation without defining what the starting point is even supposed to mean.

Comment: @dxiv I understand, then can you suggest a definition such that the above is correct?

Comment: @I'mastudent No sensible/self-consistent definition exists, see the linked q&a.

Comment: @dxiv are you talking about global definition or do you say that there is no definition, such that the above is correct?

Comment: @I'mastudent Guess you could come up with some contrived definition under which the posted statement holds true. However, such an arbitrary definition would not be 1) sensible, 2) self-consistent, and 3) "*global*", whatever that means. All that said, this is now drifting far away from the question as originally asked. I suggest you re-read the linked duplicate carefully, then - if you still have a question after that - ask a new question. Make sure to point out specifically how it's different from [others](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake-proofs?tab=Frequent) asked before.