# Where is my mistake ?$ (-1)^3=-1 \to \sqrt[3]{-1}=-1 $

Tags: exponentiation, fake-proofs

Where is my mistake ?
(In the field of real numbers)

$$ (-1)^3=-1 \to  \sqrt[3]{-1}=-1 $$

$$\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1=(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}=(-1)^{\frac{2}{6}}=\sqrt[6]{(-1)^2}=\sqrt[6]{(1)^2}=1$$

$$-1=^?1 $$

Comment: Easier $-1=(-1)^{2/2}=\sqrt{(-1)^2}=1$. But also $(-1)^{2/2}=(\sqrt{-1})^2$... ooops.

Comment: This question has been asked here approximately $200$ times.

Comment: For the record, the law $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ is only valid when **$a$ is real and positive and $b$ is real**. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1128626/18880) You implicitly used this law without satisfying the condition $a>0$ as $(-1)^{\frac26}=((-1)^2)^{\frac16}$, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That is the same error as in $1=\sqrt{1}=\sqrt{(-1)^2}=-1$

That is based on the fact: $1^\frac{1}{2} = \sqrt{1} = \pm 1$
The same is true for $1^\frac{1}{6} = \sqrt[6]{1} = \pm 1$
So you get $-1=\pm 1$ and that is true.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake lies in assuming that $(1)^{\frac{1}{6}}=1$, this is because, $1$ has two sixth roots in the field of real numbers, $1,-1$

Comment: No, $1$ being real and positive, $1^{\frac16}=1$ is perfectly well defined and unique. Nobody ever construes $e^{1/3}$ to be a (possibly!) non-real number or $e^{1/2}$ to be possibly negative.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen But, arent there 2 sixth roots of unity in the field of reals?

Comment: Yes, but the set of $n$-th roots of unity is not produced by raising $1$ to the power $1/n$, which just gives $1$. Some people will write the imaginary unit $\mathbf i$ as $\sqrt{-1}$ (though most disapprove of this notation) even fewer would write $\mathbf i=(-1)^{\frac12}$, but hardly anybody would write  $\mathbf i=1^{\frac14}$ or $\mathbf i\in1^{\frac14}$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen So, the mistake lies in notation, not in the reasoning, right?

Comment: _Your_ mistake lies in interpreting exponential notation as being set-valued, while it is single valued. However the mistake of OP is either to introduce a non-integer power of $-1$ in the first place (which I would consider not defined at all), or for those who would admit this with some choice of definition, to rewrite $a^{p/q}$ as $\sqrt[q]{a^p}$ (with $a=-1$, $p=2$, $q=6$), which is definitely not valid when $a<0$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen So then, while solving equations like $x^{2/3}=c$ in the field $\mathbb{C}$, should we not write $x=c^{3/2}$?

Comment: Indeed you should not. But $x^{2/3}=c$ is not a proper equation in hte first place for $c\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R$. One might write the equation $x^2=c^3$ if that is what you mean; it generally has $2$ solutions for $x$, neither of which I would write as $\sqrt{c^3}$, though some people might.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49196/discussion-between-vidyarthi-and-marc-van-leeuwen).