# Complex numbers polar form change

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I have a pretty straight forward question.

Change $z = (-1+i\sqrt3)^{2017}$ to $a+bi$ $\;$ form & polar form. Where $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

So i want to change it to $z = re^{iv}$.

$r$ is easy to calculate. $r = \sqrt4 = 2$.

However the angle is where im struggeling.

I know all the "standard" angles with components like:  $\frac{\sqrt3}2, \frac12, \frac1{\sqrt2}$.

However now we have $\frac{\sqrt3}{-1}$. How do you tackle this type of question?

Comment: Check out my blog article: "The Exponential Nature of the Complex Unit Circle" (https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/754.php) to get a from the ground explanation of Euler's formula and polar to-from cartesian conversion of complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation), arg$\displaystyle(-1+i\sqrt 3)=\pi+\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt3}{-1}=\pi-\dfrac\pi3$

$\implies\displaystyle -1+\sqrt3i=2e^{2\pi i /3}$

**See also**: [Euler's formula, is this true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127880/eulers-formula-is-this-true)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The point $-1+\sqrt3i$ makes an equilateral triangle together with $0$ and $-2$.

Answer (score 1):

$z = (-1+i\sqrt3)^{2017} = (2\omega)^{2017}$, where $\omega = \dfrac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}$ is the third root of unity.  ($v = \arctan(\sqrt3/(-1)) = \dfrac{2\pi}{3}$), so $$z = 2^{2017} \omega^{2017} = 2^{2017} = 2^{2017} e^{2\pi/3} \\ = 2^{2017} \, \frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2} = -2^{2016} + i \, 2^{2016}\sqrt3.$$